# Custom Post Type API doesn't show taxonomy or category array

Tags: custom-post-types, taxonomy, rest-api

Using this url http://www.my_site.it/wp-json/wp/v2/portfolio/

this is a object custom type on that json:

[image]

where are taxonomy or category array?

Answer (score 1):

The taxonomy for custom post type must be included into REST API just as the custom post itself.
Add this to your custom post taxonomy arguments array:

```
'show_in_rest' => true,
'rest_base'    => 'category',
'rest_controller_class' => 'WP_REST_Terms_Controller'
```

For more information http://v2.wp-api.org/extending/custom-content-types/